# Cannot Import Name LoginView

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a modal form in my django project. I am trying to use bootstrap modal forms and I am following an example:

https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

When I import in views.py:

`from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import BSModalCreateView`

I get an error "cannot import name LoginView" - but I'm confused because I do not have LoginView anywhere in my project. Why is this happening? This is my first time trying to use Class Based Views. I know this isn't a lot of detail, but I am completely confused here.

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import BookForm
from .models import Book
from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import BSModalCreateView

class BookCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'examples/create_book.html'
    form_class = BookForm
    success_message = 'Success: Book was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Book
from bootstrap_modal_forms.forms import BSModalForm

class BookForm(BSModalForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'price')
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your view.most probably you are using form to login user

Comment: @Gagan updated above - this view and form are taken directly from the link above in the question.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @solarissmoke I'm using django 1.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a version of Django (1.10) that is incompatible with the version of `bootstrap_modal_forms` that you have installed. `bootstrap_modal_forms` is [attempting to import `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/blob/master/bootstrap_modal_forms/generic.py#L1), which was only added in Django 1.11.

You will need to upgrade to at least Django 1.11 if you want to use `bootstrap_modal_forms`. You should probably do this anyway given that 1.10 reached [end of life](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions) a long time ago, and not secure.

Comment: thanks...is there a way that I can upgrade this current project to Django 1.11? or do I need to install that and then start back over?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Django asset folder tipically named "static/js" in the root's folder. For any reasons when you do "pip install django-bootstrap-modal-forms" the folder is not filled from the needed two files that are jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js and jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.min.js. So the solutions is:

1. create the Django asset folder as for example "static/js"
2. create the 2 empty files jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js and jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.min.js
3. go to the Github repository of the Django plugin and copy and past the content of 2 files. This is the GH [link](https://github.com/trco/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/blob/master/bootstrap_modal_forms/static/js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.min.js)
   I hope this help you